# this.setState is not a function while I am trying to set a different state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the value of `currentIndex` every 5s but when it comes to `this.setState` I receive `Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            currentIndex: 0,
       }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.changeIndex()
    }

    changeIndex() {
        const { currentIndex } = this.state
        setInterval(function () {
            if (currentIndex < 2) {
                this.setState({ currentIndex: currentIndex + 1 })
            } else {
                this.setState({ currentIndex: 0 })
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
```

Comment: because you are wrapping that in `setInterval`, whats the reason for the delay?

Comment: @Rikin I want to change the index every 5 seconds

Comment: @MarkusHayner TL;DR; use arrow function.

Comment: Also `this.setState({ currentIndex: currentIndex + 1 })` I am almost sure doesn't do what you expect it to do. If you need to update state based on the current state use callback `this.setState(currentState => ({ /* correct state here */}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function :

```
 setInterval(() => {
        if (currentIndex < 2) {
            this.setState({ currentIndex: currentIndex + 1 })
        } else {
            this.setState({ currentIndex: 0 })
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

use arrow functions:

```
changeIndex = () =>{
            const { currentIndex } = this.state
            setInterval( ()=> {
                if (currentIndex < 2) {
                    this.setState({ currentIndex: currentIndex + 1 })
                } else {
                    this.setState({ currentIndex: 0 })
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
```